# Not able to handle the URL with Special Characters through Authentication Required pop up in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, special-characters

Please find below the code I'm using.

1. Authentication Required Pop Up.
2. Using https://username:password@url in Selenium Web Driver.
3. Password contains special characters like #^[ ](
4. Password error message received. Manually its working fine.

   ```
   String result = java.net.URLEncoder.encode("925gp2i4gnqp^#(^985ghq95gqcpqjcg[0rijfm[e0rf9q", "UTF-8");

   String URL = "https://" + uname + ":" + result + "@" + TEST_ENVIRONMENT;
   String URL1 = "https://" + TEST_ENVIRONMENT;
   System.out.println(URL);
   ```

Comment: Could you share what is the error message received??

Comment: it can be the issue with `@` as well, did you try sending `%40` in place of `@`.

Comment: I got this following error in the Browser. But manually am able to login this.

ERROR:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: @pArAs no it didnt work

Comment: Any comments please, still am not able to work it out